# genfromtxt error - Got n columns instead of m

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to import data using numpy's genfromtxt with header names and non-homogeneous data types. Every time I run the program I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #8 (got 6 columns instead of 1)
    Line #9 (got 6 columns instead of 1)
    Line #10 (got 6 columns instead of 1)
    Line #11 (got 6 columns instead of 1)
    Line #12 (got 6 columns instead of 1)
```

I have already gone through this [question](http://Numpy%20genfromtxt%20error%20:%20got%20extra%20columns%20instead%20of%20n%20many)
but it didn't solve my problem. It is a very simple problem, but I can't figure out what is wrong. The code and data is included:

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('Data.dat', comments='#', delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=None).transpose()
print data
```

**Tab-separated data**

```
# -----
# -----
# -----
# -----
# -----
# -----
# -----
column_1    column_2    column_3    column_4    column_5    column_6
1   2   3   A   1   F
4   3   2   B   2   G
1   4   3   C   3   H
5   6   4   D   4   I
```

**Update**

In short what I require is a way of converting the first valid line after skip_header to be the first uncommented valid line with the optional argument names=True.

Comment: Are your column headers tab-delimited? They may be space delimited, which causes numpy to interpret it as one column.

Comment: Here it appears space-separated, but they are actually tab-separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `names=True`, `genfromtxt` expects the *first* line (after `skip_header` lines) to contain the field names, even if that line is a comment.  Apparently it is pretty common for field names to be specified in a comment.  If you have a variable number of comments *before* your uncommented field names, you'll have to work around this quirk of `genfromtxt`.  The following shows one way you could do this.

Here's my test file.  (The file is space-delimited. Add `delimiter='\t'` in the call to `genfromtxt` for a tab-delimited file).

```
In [12]: cat with_comments.dat
# Some
# comments
# here
foo bar baz
1.0 2.0 3.0
4.0 5.0 6.0
7.0 8.0 9.0
```

Open the file, and read lines until the line is not a comment:

```
In [13]: f = open("with_comments.dat", "r")

In [14]: line = f.readline()

In [15]: while line.startswith('#'):
   ....:     line = f.readline()
   ....:
```

`line` now holds the line of field names:

```
In [16]: line
Out[16]: 'foo bar baz\n'
```

Convert it to a list of names:

```
In [17]: names = line.split()
```

Give those names to genfromtxt, and read the rest of the file:

```
In [18]: data = genfromtxt(f, names=names)

In [19]: data
Out[19]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0), (7.0, 8.0, 9.0)], 
      dtype=[('foo', '<f8'), ('bar', '<f8'), ('baz', '<f8')])
```

Don't forget to close the file (or better, use `with("with_comments.dat", "r") as f:` instead):

```
In [20]: f.close()
```

Comment: How did you get Out[19]? And now, how do I convert the structured array to numpy array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get Out[19]".  That just shows the value of `data`.  (I was working in an ipython (http://ipython.org/) shell when I did this example.)  Your question about converting the structured array (which *is* a numpy array) to a "numpy array" should be a new question.  But search for similar questions first--it has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little prodding around has revealed the answer. From the `genfromtxt()` documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html):

> Note: There is one notable exception to this behavior: if the optional
>   argument names=True, the first commented line will be examined for
>   names.

Therefore, to make your code work, your data should be in the following format:

```
#column_1   column_2    column_3    column_4    column_5    column_6
#   -----
#   -----
#   -----
#   -----
#   -----
#   -----
1   2   3   A   1   F
4   3   2   B   2   G
1   4   3   C   3   H
5   6   4   D   4   I
```

Alternatively, if you have a variable number of header/comments rows, but the columns are all the same, then you could define the column names in the `genfromtxt` arguments:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(
    path, comments='#', delimiter='\t', 
    names='column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6',
    dtype=None
)
```

However, by using the `comments` keyword, `genfromtxt` will read the first row after the last comment row, which comprises your column headers. It will assume that it is part of the data, and therefore that your dtype should be string, so your data at this stage will look like this:

```
array([('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4', 'column_5', 'column_6'),
       ('1', '2', '3', 'A', '1', 'F'), ('4', '3', '2', 'B', '2', 'G'),
       ('1', '4', '3', 'C', '3', 'H'), ('5', '6', '4', 'D', '4', 'I')], 
      dtype=[('column_1', 'S8'), ('column_2', 'S8'), ('column_3', 'S8'), ('column_4', 'S8'), ('column_5', 'S8'), ('column_6', 'S8')])
```

If you know what datatype your columns should be, you first take a slice excluding the first row:

```
data1 = data[1:]
```

Then modify the `dtypes`:

```
data1.astype(np.dtype([('column_1', 'i4'),('column_2', 'i4'), ('column_3', 'i4'), ('column_4', 'S10'), ('column_5', 'i4'), ('column_6', 'S10')]))
```

Output:

```
array([(1, 2, 3, 'A', 1, 'F'), (4, 3, 2, 'B', 2, 'G'),
       (1, 4, 3, 'C', 3, 'H'), (5, 6, 4, 'D', 4, 'I')], 
      dtype=[('column_1', '<i4'), ('column_2', '<i4'), ('column_3', '<i4'), ('column_4', 'S10'), ('column_5', '<i4'), ('column_6', 'S10')])
```

Comment: You could use the `skip_header=7` keyword, as suggested by @mkrieger1.

Comment: @nxkryptor, modified answer to address your data format.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of `genfromtxt`:

> If `names` is True, the field names are read from the first valid line after the first `skip_header` lines.

In your example, you could add `skip_header=7` to the `genfromtxt` call to make it work.

Comment: I have variable commented lines depending on the data file, in other words the skip header values are variable. I have more than 5000 files, and is impossible with this method.